# Google sheets shows could not fetch URL

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I wrote few importXML functions in Google Sheet to get EMA values for a company's stock & it was working fine. Suddenly, I saw the below error

**Could not fetch URL:** https://www.topstockresearch.com/INDIAN_STOCKS/REFINERIES/Reliance_Industries_Ltd.html

**Things I tried**

I did a SO search & changed HTTPS to HTTP. This worked only for the first time. I toggled between HTTP/HTTPS back & forth but still it does not work in any of the options.

This is also a crawlable page, as I tried disabling javascript & checking if the page loads or not. The page loaded perfectly fine.

Comment: What are your functions?

Comment: I tried it, and I encountered a 403 error (forbidden). That's the problem and I have no solution.

Comment: Cell A4 = https://www.topstockresearch.com/INDIAN_STOCKS/REFINERIES/Reliance_Industries_Ltd.html. Formula Used: importxml(A4,"//*[@id='datagrid']")

Comment: Yeah I don't think there's a way around this. The web server is denying the fetch, nothing that can be done from Google sheets side

Comment: ok thank you. So its not google, the server does not allow the import.